# React Native Animated component gets covered on panning

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Works fine on iOS:  [image]

Gets covered outside of box on Android:
[image]

I read somewhere that `zIndex` only affects sibling components, though this works on iOS.
How should I go about fixing it on Android?

https://snack.expo.io/@riwu/animated-zindex

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Animated, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pos: new Animated.ValueXY(),
    };

    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        {
          dx: this.state.pos.x,
          dy: this.state.pos.y,
        },
      ]),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          marginTop: 20,
          borderWidth: 1,
          padding: 5,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        }}
      >
        <Animated.Image
          {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
          style={[this.state.pos.getLayout(), { flex: 1, zIndex: 1 }]}
          source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png' }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Since you want to render your `Image` outside of the `view` box, you can put it outside the view. Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/BJQgcF6hf) out if it helps

Comment: @PritishVaidya I want to have the border around the `Image` (before it's moved). I'm actually moving another image into the box initially (so it's like a drop zone)

Comment: Try this [one](https://snack.expo.io/ByJpaYpnM), to have `zIndex` take effect in android, you can set absolute positioning of the elements

Comment: @PritishVaidya seems like that's the only possible workaround, you can add it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `zIndex` to take effect, you need to make the position of the elements as `absolute`, to overlap each other.

Therefore the resulting code will look like this

```
  <View >
    <View
        style={{
            marginTop: 20,
            borderWidth: 1,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 1
        }}
    >

    </View>
    <Animated.Image
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[this.state.pos.getLayout(), { marginTop: 25, marginLeft: 5, height: 40, width: 40, position: 'absolute', zIndex: 2}]} //...Adding appropriate margin, height and width as per parent element
        source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png' }}
    />
</View>
```

Here's the sample snack [demo](https://snack.expo.io/ByJpaYpnM)